# Returned value is Not Found or "Specified value has invalid HTTP Header characters. Parameter name: name"

Tags: c#, jira, restsharp

Trying to get a Rest request to go through. I was able to get the Cookie from the recommended method, but am unable to process requests following. The responses listed in the title are returned under the following condition:

```
foreach(RestResponseCookie a in response.Cookies){
 if(a.Name == "JSESSIONID")
                {
                    request.AddHeader("cookie:" + a.Name, a.Value);
                }
}
response = client.Execute(request);
```

This returns the “Specified value has invalid HTTP Header characters. Parameter name: name”

When trying to instead adding this through

```
            request.AddCookie(a.Name, a.Value);
```

the return is "Not Found", although I can get the request when manually going to the site.

Edit1.

Fix was possible by handling all cookies instead of just the one that was explicitly stated by the documentation.

```
client.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
foreach(RestResponseCookie a in response.Cookies){
   if(a.Expires == new DateTime(0))//remove expiring cookie as stated in dat3450's answer
        client.CookieContainer.Add(newCookie() {Name = a.Name, Value = a.Value, Path = a.Path, Domain = a.Domain});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the above code it appears a few additional cookies are not included within the request. There are **three cookies** that are required to send a valid request via the JIRA API:

- JSESSIONID
- studio.crowd.tokenkey
- atlassian.xsrf.token

You can get these cookies in the same place you get the JSESSIONID cookie (from a valid login response). Go through all of the `Set-Cookie` headers in the response and use all of them except the `studio.crowd.tokenkey` with an `Expires` parameter.

The JIRA API reference page doesn't really show much information about this, so you can find some additional information here: https://confluence.atlassian.com/cloud/cookies-744721661.html